# Set Custom Parameter before setting @Trace(dispatcher=true) annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, newrelic

I am using newrelic to do some metric for . I got it working where it splits based on my endpoint . However I am having some trouble passing the custom parameter with new relic before the endpoints are instantiated.

I have tried using @trace with/without dispatcher flag but no luck

```
public class ServiceController {

  @Trace(dispatcher = true)
  public Response getAllUsers(Request){

  }

  @Trace(dispatcher = true)
  public Response getOneUser(Request){

  }

  //this gets triggered before any of the above calls.
  public void preProcess(){
    //adding this here ensures this gets logged without fail even if new endpoints get added in future.
    NewRelic.addCustomParameter("requsterName", context.get("name"));
  }



}
```

I am expecting with my requesterName as custom attribute
/getAllUsers 
/getOneUser

I do get the endpoints but not the requesterName

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the call to add the custom parameter is done before a Transaction is created (one is created by the @Trace(dispatcher = true)).

Adding the @Trace(dispatcher = true) to the preProcess method should allow the custom attribute to be written.